# How to override clean method with respect to related field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

There is `Order` and `Invoice` models in my app. `Order` has attribute `approved`. When admin set `approved=True` in Django-admin, customer is notified that they can pay the order (`Invoice`).

The problem is that `Invoice` has attribute `final_price` which has to be set by admin before admin can approve the order.

In Django-admin, there is `Invoice` object inlined into `Order` object. I want to allow admin to set `final_price` attribute and set `approved` order at once.

So I've overriden the `clean(self)` method of `Order`.

```
def clean(self):
    if self.approved and not self.invoice.final_price:
        raise ValidationError(_("Invoice final price has to be set on approved order!"))
```

The problem is that if Admin sets `Invoice.final_price` and `Order.approved` at once, the clean method raises `ValidationError` because it doesn't know that `Invoice` is about to be changed.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first check at the form level i.e., the input data.

Your `self.invoice.final_price` retrieves the final_price from the database, which is not yet set.

One way would be validating the final_price in its InlineFormSet itself. Another way would be getting

```
final_price = input_data.get('final_price')
if self.approved and not final_price:
   # Raise an error
```